# Does Vim or SciTE has syntax highlight support for T4 template .tt files?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, t4, scite

Does Vim or SciTE has syntax highlight support for T4 template .tt files?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you already [searched the vim scripts for any custom T4 syntax files](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-3005259998294962%3Abvyni59kjr1&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=t4&sa=Search+Vim+sites) and your search didn't yield any results too. So, there's no custom syntax file provided.

Looking at my installation of Vim 7.3, I can also find no T4 syntax file.

So, the answer to your question (at least for vim) is **nope, there's none**.

However, it's no big deal to create a syntax file by yourself. You could either take an existing syntax file, read and understand it and then create a new one based on this for T4, or have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/vi/vi-4.shtml) where syntax file creation from scratch is being explained.

A quick look at the [features of SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html) (section *Languages understood by SciTE*) looks as if there's no support for T4 by SciTE too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact there is!

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2135

Put that file in ~/.vim/syntax/ and put 'set syntax=tt' in your ~/.vimrc file, and you're all set!  Works great for me!

Comment: The file is for tintin/tt++, not for T4?

Answer (score 0):

There is a vim bundle here for T4 syntax highlighting:

https://github.com/sillyotter/t4-vim